# Connect with Wi-Fi in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working with my IoT app with Flutter's Null Safety version, and want to connect to a Wi-Fi with SSID and Password, but there is no any package which is migrated to null safety, So someone can help me to how can I connect to Wi-Fi with SSID and Password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the existing packages you'd need to run flutter without sound null safety, using either one of the following methods.

- Adjust the version constraints to use `2.9`.
- Set flutter no-sound-null-safety while running the application, with this command `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

Visit [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety#testing-or-running-mixed-version-programs) page for details instructions.